# Why does Postgres choose index scan instead of index seek to fetch one record by primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
create table documents 
(
     id serial not null primary key,
     key varchar(50) not null,
     document jsonb
);
```

It has over 100M records and when I run a query to get 1 record by primary key:

```
 select * from documents where id = 20304050
```

It uses the index scan to get it:

```
Index Scan using documents_pkey on documents (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=533) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = 20304050)
Planning Time: 0.070 ms
Execution Time: 0.024 ms
```

Why does Postgres choose to use an index scan instead of an index seek?

Edit:
I came from the SQL Server world where it was a distinction between an index scan and an index seek. In Postgres, there is no such thing as an index seek.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "index seek" in Postgres - what do you mean with that? Plus: an index scan is the right thing for the optimizer to choose here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does postgres scans all pages of the index or it uses btree to find the page with the right id?

Comment: No it does not, it's a btree and it uses a "binary search" to find that row. If you run `explain (analyze, buffers)` you can actually see how many blocks it needs to find that row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, got it, thanks. I was confused by the word index scan.

Comment: To clarify:  Some database systems, such as MS SQL Server, use the terms "index scan" and "index seek" to distinguish whether the system will scan an index page-by-page looking for the specified value(s) vs. using an optimized method such as a binary search.  Index scan = page-by-page.  Index seek = optimized method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question has already been answered in the comments. „Index scan“ in postgres is the correct way of the query planner saying: „I‘m using an index to find that row(s)“. There is no concept of „index seek“ in postgres.